# Error installing R package for Linux

Tags: r, linux, package

Im trying to install a package named "rgeos" on R 3.3, but when I type

```
install.packages("rgeos")
```

But it returns me the following error (same happens with other packages, but not all the packages):

```
> * installing *source* package ‘rgeos’ ...
** package ‘rgeos’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgeos: 0.3-19
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 524
checking for geos-config... no
no
configure: error: geos-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/home/kdg/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rgeos’
> 
> The downloaded source packages are in
>   ‘/tmp/Rtmpsa5pDo/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In
> install.packages("rgeos") :   installation of package ‘rgeos’ had
> non-zero exit status
```

Any clues how con install this package?

Comment: Do you have any geos libraries installed? On my system I have _geos_ and _geos-devel_

Comment: Thank you @user20650 it worked!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that when running R in Linux is necessary to install some build tools. As in this case, in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

Then try package install again.

[hints from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312294/once-installed-geos-library-c-and-c-and-then-trying-to-install-rgeos-packa)

Comment: If you are on Centos I suggest you to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097501/centos-libgeos-repository-missing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa instead

Comment: As an alternative: `sudo apt-get install libgeos++-dev`

Comment: @SRhm, you are right. After upgrading to R 3.5, to install rgeos i had to install `ibgeos++-dev` also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following:

```
cd /opt
git clone https://github.com/libgeos/geos
cd geos
export CC='clang' && export CXX='clang++' && export OBJC='clang'
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo -EH make install
R
install.packages('rgeos')
```

NB: `export clang` is particular to me; I am just pasting my exact solution.