# centos libgeos repository missing

Tags: centos, centos7, shapely, geos, geopandas

On centos 7.3 minimal trying to install shapely or geopandas requires access to https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos libgeos.

Trying to install this via `sudo yum install libgeos-dev` tells me that this package is not available. It seems that I am lacking a repository. So far I have been unable to find a working one as http://trac.osgeo.org/geos is pointing to https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg96 for the RPM but still after rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm the installation candidate is not found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that for CentOS this package is called `geos-devel` and can be found through RPM Fusion.

```
yum install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm
yum install geos-devel
```

Also see: https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration